# need to check if multi directorys exists

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def check_and_remove(pathslist):
    for path in pathslist:
        if os.path.exists(path) and os.path.isdir(path):
        shutil.rmtree(path, ignore_errors=true)
        print("Deleted")
    else:
        print(path, " directory not found")

dirs_to_delete = [
'C:\Directory1',
'C:\Directory2',
'C:\Directory3'
]

check_and_remove()
```

Changed the suggested shutil.rmtree(dir, ignore_errors=true) to shutil.rmtree(path, ignore_errors=true)

now getting this error -

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Temp\PycharmProjects\crm\CRMReinstall.py", line 53, in 
    check_and_remove()
TypeError: check_and_remove() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pathslist'

Comment: Can you upload the function invocation? I guess the problem lies in the `dir` variable (in `shutil.rmtree(dir, ignore_errors=true)`), since it comes from the outer scope. Perhaps you meant `path`?

Comment: Please produce a [mcve]. In the code you've shown, your function is never called.

Answer (score 0):

in `shutil.rmtree(dir, ignore_errors=true)` you are using `dir` which is python inbuilt function perhaps you want to do `shutil.rmtree(path, ignore_errors=true)`

Answer (score 0):

Replace `dir` with `path` in that line:

```
shutil.rmtree(dir, ignore_errors=true)
```

[dir](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#dir) is a built-in function of the language.

Comment: Went ahead and made change - getting new error - see above

Comment: Read the error, specially this is your code :/
You need to pass an argument to `check_and_remove()`, eg `dirs_to_delete`.

Comment: Little reminder: [stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), if the answer is good for you :)